# Roundcube filters getting ignored with postfix/dovecot/sieve

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, sieve

I'm having a lot of trouble getting roundcube filters working. I can see the filters in the roundcube web interface and I can see the sieve files in the user's home directory. I can also edit and save the filters.

However, the filters are getting ignored. For example, the spam filter is not moving spam to the junk mail folder.

Here is the dovecot config:

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %n
auth_verbose = yes
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_default = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
  sieve_default_name = Defaults
  sieve_global = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve
  sieve_user_log = ~/.dovecot.sieve.log
}
protocols = " imap sieve sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

I'm running on a debian box. I believe I'm using lda.

Answer (score 0):

Finally stumbled on some decent documentation: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Troubleshooting

I ended up installing lmtp and configured that to work with this procedure: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP

Once lmtp was installed, it started working. I never figured out how to determine if lda was installed or not. I didn't see a debian package for it.